# How do distant starlight & white holes support Young Earth Creationism?

Tags: biblical-basis, young-earth-creation, science

I read [a book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1781919992)¹ on distant starlight, the speed of light & white holes… such conjectures asserting the possibility of such making the YEC (Young Earth Creationism) position more tenable.

**Q: But according to YEC’s, how is this tenable?**

I feel like the book left me scratching my head more for lack of more content, I wonder if any astrophysics majors out there can help me fill in the blanks.

(¹ Creation and Change: Genesis 1.1-2.4 in the Light of changing Scientific Paradigms, by Douglas F. Kelly)

Comment: _In general relativity, a white hole is a hypothetical region of spacetime_  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_hole). I don't see how a 'hypothetical region' can have any bearing on the biblical record of creation, myself.

Comment: I'm not sure this is on topic for this SE, and I haven't read the book, so it's hard to comment. You might try Humphrey's [Starlight and Time](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0890512027), though, which IIRC talks about the same or similar model. The short version IIUC is that mass distorts time, and if Earth is near the center of the Universe's mass, time would move more slowly here than elsewhere, allowing starlight plenty of time to arrive and making *Earth* much younger than the rest of the Universe.

Comment: @Matthew Appreciate the info, if this isn’t the topic for CSE, can you explain the tab I put above^ which says: “young-earth-creationism”??

Comment: @NigelJ Noted, it’s certainly a possibility if it was/is hypothetical.  Yet, I suck at math & no little to nothing on astrophysics.

Comment: This SE is for discussing *Christianity*. While general YEC questions are on topic, yours a) has very little theological relevancy, and b) is asking about the sort of level of detail that would be more appropriate on a science-oriented venue. OTOH, I *did* say "I'm not sure" .

Comment: **Hypothetical** There is much in science that is hypothetical; some is substantiated by subsequent research, and some is jetisoned (i.e. string theory.  Creation science IS part of Christianity discussions. Even if some is hypothetical.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the book you read was "Starlight and Time" by D. Russell Humphreys, PhD. It's the only book I know of covering the subject.

If you've read the book then you've read pretty much everything accessible written about the subject. There are some more technical math papers associated with it that you can read if your math is up to it. I've only Bachelor level math, so it isn't. But there is really no other information out there other than the book, and some YEC articles summarizing it.

For those of you who haven't read it the essence is a hypothesis is that a combination of General Relativity and a very hypothetical gravitational distribution in the universe allows the Earth and nearby objects like the Sun to be only 6000 years old, thanks to extreme time dilation, while distant stars and the space around them are billons of years old, allowing time for their light to arrive here.

The book enjoyed a brief period of popularity and/or notoriety. The hypothesis is not given credence in mathematical circles or outside the YEC community.

Comment: The question mentions Creation and Change: Genesis 1.1-2.4 in the Light of changing Scientific Paradigms, by Douglas F. Kelly. My guess is they're the same or similar hypothesis being discussed, though.

Comment: Some information that could be incorporated into the answer: [book entry @ Amazon](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B003BVJCQI/), about [David Russell Humphreys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell_Humphreys) (PhD in Physics), rebuttal in a 1998 [CEN Tech Journal](https://creationwiki.org/Journal_of_Creation) article [*Starlight and Time* is the Big Bang](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/247638890_Papers_Starlight_and_Time_is_the_Big_Bang) by Samuel R. Conner and [Don Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Page_(physicist)) (theoretical physics prof at the University of Alberta, Canada).

Comment: @DJClayworth Thanks for the info, I have not read that particular book you’re speaking of; I’ll check it out later.